# Copy Commit from Trunk to Branch

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

I always commit to Trunk and Branch.

Usually I:

1. create a patch of my trunk-changes I want to commit.
2. execute the patch to my workcopy of the branch (sometimes merge)
3. test trunk, test branch
4. commit the patched trunk
5. commit the patched branch

Today my mistake was that I committed all my changes(see 4) without making an patch (see 1).

Now, I have no patch that I can execute to the branch.

How can I "easily" get my changes onto the branch now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use 'svn log' to find the revision number you committed (say it turns out to be revision 314). Then use svn diff -r313:314 >patch.txt to get the patch file representing your changes.

However, I'd suggest in general you'd be better to use svn merge to merge stuff like this.